# Mesh on a graph with a curve

Tags: plotting

Assume a function that we plot:

```
 Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,10}]
```

I want to mesh the background, meaning to have cells on the background of the graph. My question stands for simple patterns such as squares, or more complicated patterns, such as triangles. (update : for example, one answer that I get here is to use GridLines->Automatic , it is to that kind of background mesh that I refer). How can I do it ?

Comment: What about `GridLines`?

Comment: Thx ! It looks nice but what if I want triangles for example ? I don't find in GridLines such a possibility.

Comment: Please edit your question so that clearly explains what you mean by "mesh in the background". As it now stands, it may closed for being unclear.

Comment: "what if I want triangles" - should have mentioned that in your post, as that is a more elaborate problem

Answer (score 3):

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

**addendum triangles**

```
R = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 10 && -1 <= y <= 1, {x, y}]
Show[{ DiscretizeRegion[R], Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Can u use that method with rectangular triangles ?

Comment: Probably yes if you know how to use `Discretize`. Alternatively, if your mesh is simple, you could mesh manually (Graphics)

Comment: @J.A Next time, please specify all your wishes right from the start before others waste their time to make proposals that you reject due to hidden constraints.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I did not reject any of them. I'm just curious about other possibilities.